# Props are empty in React-route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, url-routing

This is the definition of my router:

```
import BugsOverview from './BugsOverview';
import BugDetail from './BugDetail';
import './index.css';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router'

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Login} />
    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
    <Route path="/bugs-overview" component={Bugs} />
    <Route path="/bugs-overview/:bugID" component={BugsDetails} />
    <Route path="/logout" component={Logout} />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

var BugsDetails = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (<div>
      <h1>Bug Detail</h1>
      <BugDetail />
    </div>
    );
  }
});
```

And this is my BugDetail component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {  browserHistory, Router } from 'react-router';

class BugDetail extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, ctx) {
    super(props);
    console.log(props);// -->> {}
    console.log(props.route);// -->> undefined
    console.log(props.params);// -->> undefined
    console.log(ctx);// -->> {}
    this.state = {
      un: "un",
      pw: "pw"
    };
  }

  getBugID(){
      return (
          <span> {this.props.params.bugID} </span>
      )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        Detail voor bug met id {this.getBugID()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default BugDetail;
```

The problem is that `props` object is always empty, so i can't reach to the argument in my component. With other words:  if the users navigate to `http://localhost:3000/bugs-overview/anBugID`, i can't detect the value `anBugID`.

I have seen many questions and pages about this but none of them did do the trick for this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the component you pass to `<Route component=` will receive param information, just like passing props from any component to another. They won't skip any components in your tree. You would need to pass the props to `BugDetail` from `BugDetails`.

```
var BugsDetails = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Bug Detail</h1>
        <BugDetail 
          {...this.props} // this syntax passes all props
          params={this.props.params} // or pass them individually 
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

If you don't want to have to pass props there are a few solutions, such as putting prop information on context yourself, or depending on your version of react-router some other method like `withRouter`